# Mac mini, two monitors over hdmi and Thunderbolt simultaneously

Tags: mac-mini

Will the new Mac Mini (mid-level, quad-core) support the following two
monitors simultaneously: one an Apple Cinema Display 30", 2560x1600
resolution, connected to both the Thunderbolt port and one USB port via the
Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI adaptor (this thing:
http://store.apple.com/ca/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi
-adapter)
 and the other monitor a Samsung with 1600 x 1200 resolution connected to
the Mini Mac by the hdmi port, using the hdmi-to-dvi adaptor Apple gives you
with the Mac Mini?

I have read in some places that hdmi cannot output better than 1920 x 1080,
but 1600 x 1200 is actually fewer pixels and I have read differing accounts
of whether it will work.

For the Apple Cinema Display, currently on my MacBook Pro 2009 I run it
using the adaptor I mentioned above, and it needs to connect to one USB port
as well as to the miniDisplay Port. I am guessing that the Thunderbolt port
will serve instead of the miniDisplay Port and I will still need to connect
to one USB port on the Mini, in addition to the Thunderbolt port.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work.

The maximum for HDMI 1.0 is actually 1920x1200, not 1080. Later revisions can go higher, but [previous Mac mini HDMI ports have been limited to 1920x1200](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP632) and there's no reason to believe it would have changed.

Comment: Thank you! And do you know if the 30" cinema display will still need an extra USB port on the new Mac Mini, like it does on the MacBook Pro, or will the Thunderbolt port be enough?

Comment: It'll still need it. Thunderbolt ports can output Mini-Displayport, and they might be able to supply enough power for the adapter, but the adapter won't be designed to take advantage of that.